# Rails 3 CSRF - Disable in selected controllers only and prevent from beeing rendered in Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

This my seem like a common problem. There's a lot of stuff related to disabling CSRF in Rails.

What I would like to achieve is to prevent the token from being rendered in views. Even if I entirely remove *protect_from_forgery* the token is still rendered in all forms. Setting *config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection* to *false* indeed makes the token go away for good, but again - I only want it to be disabled for selected actions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form_for ... , :authenticity_token => false

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for